# Kotlin SENDTO when email has multiple accounts

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, sender, sendto

I have an email app with multiple accounts(GMail, personal, work, etc). When i execute the intent to SENDTO, there is no from email account in the email. There is no way to specify the account to use.
Has anyone solved this issue?
The mailto, subject, etc is all good. but there is no sender.

i have searched for example code to specify the sender in an intent but have not found any.

desperate for an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.